# Determine if an image needs contrasting automatically in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv

OpenCV has a handy cvEqualizeHist() function that works great on faded/low-contrast images.
 However when an already high-contrast image is given, the result is a low-contrast one. I got the reason - the histogram being distributed evenly and stuff.

Question is - how do I get to know the difference between a low-contrast and a high-contrast image?

I'm operating on Grayscale images and setting their contrast properly so that thresholding them won't delete the text i'm supposed to extract (thats a different story).
   Suggestions welcome - esp on how to find out if the majority of the pixels in the image are light gray (which means that the equalise hist is to be performed)
 Please help!

**EDIT**: thanks everyone for many informative answers. But the standard deviation calculation was sufficient for my requirements and hence I'm taking that to be the answer to my query.

Comment: I need to calculate the contrast of an image. I did it by calcualting "meanStdDev" of an image. Am I right? Sometimes I am getting the SD value More than 100. What would be the threshold for a good Contrast. And what is the range of SD to convert it into a scale of 100.

Comment: well divide SD by 255, since the value of a pixel, assuming 8-bit image, cannot be more than that. then multiply by your suitable scale e.g. 100. this is called normalization. rest you can try out different images

Comment: Thanks, I have did that. What is the threshold rnage of a good image would be?

Comment: @2vision2 well i'm sorry thats something not possible to randomly say. best thing: you check the values on a few images and figure it out yourself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably just use a simple statistical measure of the image to determine whether an image has sufficient contrast. The variance of the image would probably be a good starting point. If the variance is below a certain threshold (to be empirically determined) then you can consider it to be "low contrast".

Comment: It's true that variance increases with contrast for a given image, but because it's a statistical measure it ignores spatial relationships within the image.  So it *may* work as a reliable contrast indicator sometimes, but often it won't.

Comment: @AruniRC I need to calculate the contrast of an image. I did it by calcualting "meanStdDev" of an image. Am I right? Sometimes I am getting the SD value More than 100. What would be the threshold for a good Contrast. And what is the range of SD to convert it into a scale of 100.

Answer (score 6):

If you're adjusting contrast just so you can threshold later on, you may be able to avoid the contrast adjustment step if you set your threshold adaptively using [Ohtsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method).

If you're still interested in finding out the image contrast, then read on.

While there are a [number of different ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)#Formula) to calculate "contrast".  Often, those metrics are applied locally as opposed to the entire image, to make the result more sensitive to image content:

- Divide the image into adjacent non-overlaying neighborhoods.
- Pick neighborhood sizes that are approximate to size of the features of your image (e.g. if your main feature is horizontal text, make neighborhoods tall enough to capture 2 lines of text, and just as wide).
- Apply the metric to each neighborhood individually
- Threshold the metric result to separate low and high variance blocks.  This will prevent such things as large, blank areas of page skewing your contrast estimates.

From there, you can use a number of features to determine contrast:

- The proportion of high metric blocks to low metric blocks
- High metric block mean
- Intensity distance between the high and low metric blocks (using means, modes, etc)

This may serve as a better indication of image contrast than global image variance alone.  Here's why:

[image] (stddev: 50.6)

[image] (stddev: 7.9)

The two images are perfectly in contrast (the grey background is just there to make it obvious it's an image), but their standard deviations (and thus variance) are completely different.

Comment: i did apply Otsu's thresholding method initially, however the text portion and its background went black. On equalising histogram then thresholding it was alright.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment -- it got added by accident.  Did local contrast calculations get you anywhere?  I haven't seen the images you work with so it's hard for me to suggest anything on top of what has already been said.  If you post a sample image your question may become easier to answer.

Comment: sorry for the late response (if you're still around :P). currently finishing a contour extraction coding after which i'll start contrast adjustments. a simple standard dev with experimentally determined cut-offs seems workable.

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate [cumulative histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Cumulative_histogram) of image.
2. Make linear regression of cumulative histogram in the form `y(x) = A*x + B`.
3. Calculate [RMSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation) of `real_cumulative_frequency(x)-y(x)`.
4. If that RMSE is close to zero - image is already equalized. (That means that for equalized images cumulative histograms must be linear)

Idea is taken from [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/contrast_transform/node3.html).

**EDIT:**
I've illustrated this approach in [my blog](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2011/01/algorithm-to-determine-image-contrast.html) (C example code included).

Comment: :: Isn't just std enough....<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)>... Your comments will be helpful...

Comment: There are many different ways to calculate contrast. But in my opinion if OP tries to discover `cvEqualizeHist()` was performed on image or not - then you must take into account specifics of [histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) to detect that operation (or it's absence) in image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a support provided in skimage for this. `skimage.exposure.is_low_contrast`. [reference](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#is-low-contrast)

example :

```
>>> image = np.linspace(0, 0.04, 100)
>>> is_low_contrast(image)
    True
>>> image[-1] = 1
>>> is_low_contrast(image)
    True
>>> is_low_contrast(image, upper_percentile=100)
    False
```